# Hazelcast 4.2 standalone as a linux service

Tags: linux, hazelcast

I have Hazelcast 4.2 runs in a linux server in a standalone mode by running the following files in background:

hazelcast core : `bin/start.sh`

hazelcast management center : `management-center/bin/start.sh`

I am looking for a way to make Hazelcast and management center runs as a Linux service using the start.sh files in order to make it easier to run and stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created few scripts to show how could a Hazelcast IMDG systemd service look like. Find it here: https://github.com/kwart/hazelcast-linux-service

In the heart of the solution is service script `/etc/systemd/system/hazelcast.service`:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Hazelcast IMDG
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/hazelcast/hazelcast.conf
User=hazelcast
ExecStart=/opt/hazelcast/bin/start.sh
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Creating `/etc/hazelcast` with config files (`hazelcast.conf` and `hazelcast.xml`) is optional, but it can be handy to have the possibility to tweak the config on the standard location.

The custom `hazelcast.xml` just enables basic REST endpoints.

```xml
<hazelcast xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
           http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-4.2.xsd">
    <network>
        <rest-api enabled="true"/>
    </network>
</hazelcast>
```

The `hazelcast.conf` can set java options and the path to the custom `hazelcast.xml`.

```ini
JAVA_OPTS=-Dhazelcast.config=/etc/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
MIN_HEAP_SIZE=1g
MAX_HEAP_SIZE=1g
```

*Edit 2021-04-01*
A similar approach can be used for the Management Center. A simple service file `/etc/systemd/system/hazelcast-mc.service` could look like:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Hazelcast Management Center
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
User=hazelcast
ExecStart=/opt/hazelcast-mc/bin/start.sh
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```